# model name in obsever - use full or alias

Tags: module, magento-1, event-observer, configuration

When creating an observer, in config is there a preference over the two following styles and if so which and why?

```
            <observers>
                <me_mymodule>
                    <class>me_mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>observe</method>
                </me_mymodule>
            </observers>
```

or

```
            <observers>
                <me_mymodule>
                    <classMe_Mymodule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>observe</method>
                </me_mymodule>
            </observers>
```

e.g. use the full class name or the class alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this one, especially if you write community extensions:

```
<class>me_mymodule/observer</class>
```

This way, the normal Magento class loader is used and others can use class rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

I've always done them like:

```
            <observers>
                <GattacaWebLab_Subscriber_Newsletter_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>GattacaWebLab_Subscriber_Model_Newsletter_Observer</class>
                    <method>exportSubscriber</method>
                </GattacaWebLab_Subscriber_Newsletter_Observer>
            </observers>
```

But looking at the instantiation code it should work both ways, However in my opinion it looks neater like this